# Does honcho have a .honcho file like foreman?

Tags: foreman

With foreman, if you have a file `.foreman` in the directory you issue your foreman command, it will look in it to find the env and procfile, e.g.:

```
procfile: Procfile.dev
env: conf/development.env
```

Does honcho have the equivalent?  I tried .honcho but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Procfile` as a filename, the rest is the same.